# DrEdit app traceback on redirect - raise httplib.HTTPexception()

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I'm testing DrEdit app to see how GDrive auth flow works. I already installed DrEdit on GAE. App works, but after redirect app fails by traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/_webapp25.py", line 714, in __call__
    handler.get(*groups)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~szuf-dredit/2.367896330013329954/main.py", line 327, in get
    creds = self.GetCodeCredentials()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~szuf-dredit/2.367896330013329954/main.py", line 187, in GetCodeCredentials
    creds = oauth_flow.step2_exchange(code)
  File "lib/oauth2client/client.py", line 1069, in step2_exchange
    headers=headers)
  File "lib/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1445, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "lib/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1197, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "lib/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1167, in _conn_request
    response = conn.getresponse()
  File "lib/httplib2/__init__.py", line 999, in getresponse
    raise httplib.HTTPException()
HTTPException
```

What is wrong? Have you any tips? Thanks from advance :)

Comment: Seems to work for me, are you still having the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a transient issue that has subsequently been fixed. Sorry you had to endure it.